# Getting error while running multiple docker containers of SonarQube

Tags: docker, sonarqube, amazon-ecs

I'm trying to run 2 task of same SonarQube container using the AWS ECS service (EC2 instances and not Fargate). Only 1 ECS instance is running and I'm using the EBS volumes for storing the sonar data and sonar extensions like this:-

```
/opt/sonarqube/data
/opt/sonarqube/extensions
```

If I run just 1 ECS Task (1 docker container of SonarQube) then the SonarQube application runs perfectly and I can access it however if I scale the service to additional task (means 2 docker containers of SonarQube on same ECS instance) then I get below locking error hence one of the task never comes to 'RUNNING' state:-

```
2021-03-18 10:39:19at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:289) ~[elasticsearch-7.10.2.jar:7.10.2]
2021-03-18 10:39:192021.03.18 05:09:19 ERROR es[][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] uncaught exception in thread [main]
2021-03-18 10:39:19org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to obtain node locks, tried [[/opt/sonarqube/data/es7]] with lock id [0]; maybe these locations are not writable or multiple nodes were started without increasing [node.max_local_storage_nodes] (was [1])?
2021-03-18 10:39:19at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:174) ~[elasticsearch-7.10.2.jar:7.10.2]
```

How can I make sure this issue does not come up and I can scale the service as and when required using the autoscaling feature?

Cheers,

Comment: Have you tried to configure `node.max_local_storage_nodes` to a number >1 as suggested? I don't know SonarQube but it looks like the way it works is that you need to explicitly tell it there is more than one SonarQube process/server that needs to access the data folder.

Comment: How to configure this? On Docker container or ECS Instance level?

Comment: I interpreted it as an application setting. [This forum thread](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonarqube-failing-on-kubernetes-eks-with-persisten-storage-and-rolling-update-deploymentstrategy/24294/5) seems to point, towards the end, to some sort of licensing thing.